# Can I capture this text in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a system to do with images, and if some parameters are invalid, rather than returning an image the script just has to die with some text. This all works fine in a browser, the user can tell what's going on, but now I'm creating a form to set the params, iv'e come across an issue.

I'm using `$('#img').attr('src', theUrl)` to load a preview, but if the parameters are invalid, I get the broken image icon, as it returns just text, not an image.

Is there anyway I can capture the text, so I can display to the user exactly what went wrong? I tried looking in the event from an `.error(function(event){` handler, but I couldn't see anything useful there.

Comment: _if the parameters are invalid_ what parameters are we talking about? Post a relevant example.

Comment: What text are you trying to capture in a variable? Isn't the text already in your variable `theUrl`?

Comment: @LShetty for example, you have to pass a public key, and ids of customers, but if the public key doesn't have access to any of the customers, the script can't get any further, so it throws an error, "The key cannot manage any of the customer ID's", which is output to the browser. That's the text I want to capture in javascript, so I can show the user why it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what kind of text you get back. And weither you control that... You could use `$.get` to get theUrl and see what you got in return:

```
$.get({
  url: theUrl,
  success: function(data) {
    // check weither what you got back is an image or a text...

  }
});
```

When you do control the returned img/text you could change that code to return an errorcode instead of a HTTP 200:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'HEAD',
  url: theUrl,
  success: function() {
    $('#img').attr('src', theUrl);
  },
  error: function() {
    // do something with the error
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, using the `$.ajax` method worked. I could use the `error: function(data){ var errorText = data.responseText; }` to get the text if the script dies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img src="test.jpg" id="test"> <!-- I have a image named test.jpg -->
<img src="test_2.jpg" id="test2"> <!-- I dont have a image named test_2.jpg -->
```

jQuery

```
$('#test').on('error', function(e){
  console.log(e);
  console.log('This will not give a error');
});
$('#test2').on('error', function(e){
  console.log(e);
  console.log('This will have a error');
});
```

And if you get an error on that image you could use .css or .addClass and set the image to display none. 
And display an error message to the user.